# flutter launcher icon didn't work for me i already follow all the instructions

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[what is it mean? is it successful ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofUWz.jpg)

flutter_launcher_icon didn't work with me, already follow all the instructions and the icon still not change

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Although you can use appicon.co, and replace the default flutter icon with the icon you down from appicon.co.

If you still need assistance with using flutter_launcher_icon, then please share your pubspec.yaml code.

Answer (score 1):

No need of any plugins
go to https://appicon.co
then add your app icon there and download the zip file which will contain
app icon for both android and iOS
and replace the following in your project with the downloaded one,
1.In Android
go to android->app->src->main->res
and replace android icons here
2.In IOS
go to iOS->Runner->Assets.xcassets
then replace the folder "AppIcon.appiconset" with the downloaded one
Thats it, once restart the project an run your app icon will be updated

Comment: should i rename the icon in dependecies?

Comment: no need to rename, the downloaded icons will have the same name ,you just need to replace it